# Firebase Recycler Adapter not working in signed apk

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

First is Debug APK Result & Second is Signed APK Result:

[image: Img 1] 
[image: Img 2]

Well, below is the code: 
I have searched stack for similar questions but nothing helped me.

```
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<EventDisplayModel,PostViewHolder> fireImageAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<EventDisplayModel, PostViewHolder>
            (EventDisplayModel.class,R.layout.parent_event_display_style,PostViewHolder.class,dbRef)
    {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(PostViewHolder viewHolder, EventDisplayModel model, int position) {
            viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
            viewHolder.setDescription(model.getDescription());
            viewHolder.setDownload_URL(getApplicationContext(), model.getDownload_URL());
            viewHolder.setDateTime(model.getDate_Time());
            if(model.getLat_Lng()==null)
            {
                viewHolder.setVenue(model.getVenue());
            }
            else
            {
                viewHolder.setLat_Lng(model.getLat_Lng());
            }
        }
    };

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(fireImageAdapter);
```

This is the postviewholder class

```
public static class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    View mView;

    public PostViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title){
        TextView post_title = mView.findViewById(R.id.tvPostTitle);
        post_title.setText(title);
    }

    void setDescription(String description){
        TextView post_desc = mView.findViewById(R.id.tvPostDesc);
        post_desc.setText("Description : " + description);
    }

    //Set Download_URL
    //Set Date_time
    //Set Venue
    //Set Lat_Lng      
}
```

Lastly :

```
public class EventDisplayModel {

private String Title;
private String Description;
private String Download_URL;
private String Date_Time;
private String Venue;
private String Lat_Lng;

public EventDisplayModel(){}

public EventDisplayModel(String title, String description, String download_URL, String date_Time, String venue, String lat_Lng) {
    Title = title;
    Description = description;
    Download_URL = download_URL;
    Date_Time = date_Time;
    Venue = venue;
    Lat_Lng = lat_Lng;
}
   //Getter and setter methods here
}
```

So, where am i going wrong? I'm wondering to take it out of the production version.

Comment: Have you started listening in `onStart()` method?

Comment: I haven't used a listener. Once the user selects events, this activity is opened. This code is in onCreate()

Comment: I forgot to notify that... Title is being fetched by the adapter but others are null

Answer (score 0):

Hey you need to check for proguard rules.

If you have forgot to include dependency in proguard this problem will occur.

Comment: Proguard is not enabled. minifiENabled is false.

Comment: You have to check your response first. Wether you are gettingg the response or not

Comment: How do you debug signed apks?

Comment: use PostMaster chrome extension make the request, and check. or you can use firebase analytics or crashlytics for logging the response.

Comment: I just checked. Well there was no error/exception in the log and in the Google play console.

Answer (score 0):

First make the `fireImageAdapter` variable global.

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<EventDisplayModel,PostViewHolder> fireImageAdapter;
```

Then just remove `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<EventDisplayModel,PostViewHolder>` where you intialize the adapter.

So in order to solve this, you need to override the `onStart()` method and add the following line of code:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    fireImageAdapter.startListening();
}
```

Comment: fireImageAdapter doesn't have that method. My firebase ui version is 0.4.0

Comment: In this case, I strongly recommend you to change your Firebase-UI with the last version, which is for the moment, [3.2.2](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) and to use its new features.

Comment: Have you tried to use the last version of Firebase-UI?

Comment: No, the company wanted the update asap and It's a huge task to refactor the code with firebase ui so I decided to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I know its late but for future

check your gradle file its release should look like this

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
```

}

Keep you Proguard File as it says in Documentation

more -> make sure that you have your SHA both Release and Debug in Firebase console added and the fresh googleservices file is available in your project

Thanks